# SQLite: incrementing a value of type "real"

Tags: android

My intention:
I am trying to increment a value in an SQLite column. The column is of type "REAL".

The issue:
when I am performing the incrementation (using UPDATE), nothing happens and the column is NOT being updated. I get a -1 on the cursor mCount, mPos and mRowIdColumnIndex.

My investigation:
I found out (by importing my db to the PC and opening it with SQLite Database Browser) that I cannot increment a value of type "real" when the initial value is NULL, so I added "myColumn real DEFAULT 0.0" to my table create method. This sets the value to 0.0 that can be later incremented.

SQLiteQuery: 
UPDATE ts_stocks SET score= (score + 1.0) WHERE stock_id=35 AND t_id=1

My table structure:

```
create table ts_stocks (_id integer primary key autoincrement,
        t_id integer, 
        stock_id integer,
        score real DEFAULT 0.0,
        datetime text not null,
        FOREIGN KEY(t_id) REFERENCES ts(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);  
        FOREIGN KEY(stock_id) REFERENCES stocks(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

My code:

```
public Cursor updateParticipantScore(TParticipant tParticipant, Long tId)
{
    String queryUpdateParticipantScore = "UPDATE " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_TS_STOCKS_NAME +
            " SET " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_SCORE +
            "= (" + 
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_SCORE + 
            " + " + 
            tournamentParticipant.getScore() +
            ") WHERE " + 
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_ID +
            "=" +
            tParticipant.getStock().getId() +
            " AND " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_TOURNAMENT_ID +
            "=" +
            tId;

    Cursor resultSetCursor = mDb.rawQuery(queryUpdateParticipantScore, null);

    return resultSetCursor;
}
```

This code creates the above mentioned SQL:

UPDATE ts_stocks SET score= (score + 1.0) WHERE stock_id=35 AND t_id=1

As taken from a running application debugger. Using this SQL statement on a downloaded db WORKS - it increments "score" in the correct manner.

Anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, D

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be doing updates using `rawQuery`

```
mDb.rawQuery(queryUpdateParticipantScore, null);
```

try:

```
mDb.execSQL(queryUpdateParticipantScore);
```

or even better, format your query once, create a `SQLiteStatement` and bind your arguments *something like this*:

```
static final String UPDATE_PARTICIPANTS_SCORE = "UPDATE " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_TS_STOCKS_NAME +
            " SET " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_SCORE +
            "= (" + 
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_SCORE + 
            " + ?) WHERE " + 
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_STOCK_ID +
            "=? AND " +
            StConstants.TblTsStocks.TBL_COLUMN_TS_STOCKS_TOURNAMENT_ID +
            "=?";
SQLiteStatement mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement;

public .. whereEverYouInitializeYourStuff() {
    mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement = mDb.compileStatement(UPDATE_PARTICIPANTS_SCORE);
}

public int updateParticipantScore(TParticipant tParticipant, Long tId)
{
    mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement.bindDouble(1, tParticipant.getScore());
    mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement.bindLong(2, tParticipant.getStock().getId());
    mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement.bindLong(3, tId);
    return mUpdateParticipantsScoreStatement.executeUpdateDelete();
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I use rawQuery? What is the advantage of execSQL? I read the documentation but I couldn't see any info regarding why to favor A over B. I also lack the understanding of what advantages SQLiteStatement  gives me. Could you please share some information on that? Many thanks! :)

Comment: The primary reason is that rawQuery won't actually .. do.. your UPDATE/INSERT or DELETE. SQLiteStatements are pre-formatted, pre-compiled & re-usable SQL statements that escape & bind their data properly. Not having to compile your SQL queries over & over = better performance. Data binding = escaping bad characters in Strings etc. It's a good habit to avoid using raw SQL unless you are writing CREATE TABLE statements in your SQLiteOpenHelper. The DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper in the SDK class uses SQLiteStatments internally for instance.

Comment: thank you for the valuable information. I will change my code and let the community know of the results for generations to come.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens - I changed to:

```
mDb.execSQL(queryUpdateParticipantScore);
```

and now it is working, so my SQL syntax was basically correct. 
In a few days, when I have time to go over all of my code, I intend to change it to use the

```
SQLiteStatement
```

Many thanks for teaching me something new!
D.